# Conforming to a Obj-C protocol in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have the following protocol (written in Objective-C)

```
@protocol MCRequestHandler <NSObject>
@required
-(void) handleRequest: (MCRequest*) request
                Error: (NSError*) error
                 User: (id) user;
@end
```

I'm trying to use it in Swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MCRequestHandler {

//... 

    func handleRequest(request: MCRequest!, Error error: NSError!, User user: AnyObject!) {
    }
}
```

The compiler produces two explanations of the error:

1)

> Protocol requires function 'handleRequest(_:error:user:)' with type
>   '(MCRequest!, error: NSError!, user: AnyObject!) -> Void'

2)

> Objective-C method 'handleRequest:Error:User:' provided by method
>   'handleRequest(_:Error:User:)' does not match the requirement's
>   selector ('handleRequest:error:user:')

If I take the XCode's suggestion and change my function to:

```
func handleRequest(request: MCRequest!, error Error: NSError!, user User: AnyObject!)
```

The error stays the same.

What is going on?

If I change my protocol method to this (note the capitalisation change):

```
-(void) handleRequest: (MCRequest*) request
                error: (NSError*) Error
                 user: (id) User;
```

Swift works BUT I don't want to change my protocol header because I have lots of other protocols which are capitalised in the exact same way.

Comment: Change the signature.  You're not following long-established conventions, and you're now suffering for it.  Apple's Objective-C/Swift bridging is predicated on following conventions.  You're not going to win this battle.

Comment: As indicated in the linked Q&A, this is a problem if imported Objective-C methods have argument labels starting with a capital letter. In your case the  workaround would be `@objc(handleRequest:Error:User:) func handleRequest(request: MCRequest!, error: NSError!, user: AnyObject!) { ... }`.

Comment: @Avi Sometimes you have to work with what you get ;) Still, MartinR's solution works perfectly in my case.